Pytorch - Keep first K repeating values
I have 2, 1D tensors of the same size, one tensor contains values representing an id whilst another tensor contains a value associated with that id.
E.g
ids   : tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
values: tensor([2, 7, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 2])

I want to keep the first K values and ids for each unique id:
# keeping first 3 (NOTE: since there are only 2 of ids 1, simply keep the 2)
ids   : tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
values: tensor([2, 7, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3])

I'm not sure how to go about this efficiently. A single for loop counting the ids runs too slowly.
Additional Context
I'm using this to attempt to load balance the distribution of tokens for a Mixture of Experts transformer model.
Say there is some input:
# [batch, tokens, values]
x = torch.randn(2, 10, 3)

And the router logits:
# 5 experts to choose from
gate = torch.nn.Linear(3, 5)
logits = torch.nn.functional.softmax(gate(x), dim=-1, dtype=torch.float)

I first get the selected experts per token from the router:
weights, selected = torch.topk(logits, 1)
weights, selected = map(lambda x: x.squeeze(dim=-1), (weights, selected))

Given some capacity C, I then want each expert to not process more than C tokens. Additionally, if there are more than C tokens given to an expert it should process those with the highest weighting given by the router and skip the rest.
I'm not really sure how to go about this efficiently. Here is my attempt, and thus where this question comes from:
First sort the values by expert and their respective weights:
importance = selected + weights
indices = torch.argsort(importance, descending=True)

# selected and weights will now be ordered by expert and within each expert by router weight
selected = torch.gather(selected, -1, indices)
weights = torch.gather(weights, -1, indices)

loop through each expert and process
result = torch.zeros_like(x)
for i, expert in enumerate(experts):
  batch, token = torch.where(selected == i)

  # map tokens to point to correct indices in input
  token = indices[batch, token]

  # Here `batch` represents the "ids" in the original question
  # and `token` represents the "values" in the original question
  # 
  # This is where I need to keep the first K for each "batch" where K is
  # the capacity `C`

  # compute result
  results[batch, token] += expert(
    inputs[batch, token]
  )

